# IntelliJ - Why Is This an Unchecked Assignment?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am running IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.2 and have an inspection warning `Unchecked assignment: 'anonymous javafx.scene.control.TableCell' to 'javafx.scene.control.TableCell<com.something.RepStats,java.lang.Integer>'` on the following code block:

```
colTopRepsRank.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<RepStats, Integer>, TableCell<RepStats, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell<RepStats, Integer> call(TableColumn<RepStats, Integer> param) {
            return new TableCell() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    setGraphic(null);
                    setText(empty ? null : getIndex() + 4 + "");
                }
            };
        }
    }
);
```

I am trying to figure out why that is happening. If I do follow IntelliJ's suggestion to make the `call()` method return just a `javafx.scene.control.TableCell` instead, I get other errors because the `TableColumn` is expecting the `TableCell<RepStats, Integer>`.

Comment: Don't you need to return a new TableCell<something> instead of a raw TableCell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error because `TableCell` (without type parameters) has less type information than `TableCell<RepStats, Integer>` (the former could be a `TableCell` for another table view/item combination).

In order to fix it, it should suffice to return a properly typed `TableCell` in your `call()` implementation like:

```
return new TableCell<RepStats, Integer>() {
  @Override
  protected void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
  // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Or now with Java 9, `return new TableCell<>() {` (haven't tested myself, but diamond operator should work in Java 9 on denotable types).

Comment: @MarkPeters that works in Java 8.

MartinStettner, thank you; this worked out for me!

Comment: @Zephyr: You sure about that?  I get an error "Cannot use '<>' with anonymous inner classes".  The diamond operator was introduced in Java 7 yes, but the ability to use it on anonymous inner classes to my knowledge started with Java 9.  See here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8062373

Answer (score 1):

That's because the method expects as a return type a `TableCell<RepStats, Integer>` and you return a TableCell where the types aren't defined. That means that you should add generic with the types the method expects.
Try this:

```
...
return new TableCell<RepStats, Integer>() {...}
```